# Subsonic flight in saturated steam vs. air

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, aircraft

I am wondering whether differences in density, temperature, viscosity, drag coefficient, or lift coefficient between steam and air might affect subsonic flight through these media. Let's assume machine powered flight.

I would like an answer which describes which (if any) of these factors is most important, and why (or why not).

Some properties of steam and air (which I have not fact-checked):

https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/saturated-steam-properties-d_101.html

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Tables/viscosity.html

I am inspired in part by this closed question: [Can a bird fly through steam?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/659160/can-a-bird-fly-through-steam)

Comment: 1 atm of steam is as ideal a gas as 1 atm of air (pretty much). The density is only about ~2/3 that of air (mass 18 for water, mass 28 for N2). So you get the same density in steam at 1 atm as in air at about 4000 meters elevation. Birds fly that high, as do airplanes.